# how do I resolve this node-sass installation error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, saas, failed-installation

> npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...--END PGP SIGNATURE--'

I keep getting this error while trying to install node-saas. I have even tried disabling anti-virus & windows defender.

I am using this command to install node sass:

`npm install node-sass`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the below steps:

1. Please delete your `package.lock.json` file, along with that delete your `node_modules` folder.
2. Then clear all your npm cache by `npm cache clean --force`.
3. Install node-sass `globally` by using `npm install -g node-sass`
4. Once done with `node-sass` that run your `npm install && npm start`.

Hope this should work fine.